# sign up and create new object at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise

i'm new in Ruby on Rails.
I was trying to register a new user with devise and at the same time, create a new Company object. The association between them : User belongs to Company. Company has many users. I tried to make it based on this link : http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast, but it didnt work. it said : "undefined method for Company", which is Company doesnt have email attribute.
and in sign up form, i only put email attribute for user

```
<div class="title"><%= t('.signup') %></div>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="control-group"><%= f.label :email, t('.email') %>
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div class="control-group"><%= f.label :password, t('.password') %>
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<div class="control-group"><%= f.label :password_confirmation, t('.password_confirmation') %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

<%= f.fields_for :company_attributes do |f_company| %>

<div class="control-group"><%= f_company.label :name, t('.company_name') %>
<%= f_company.text_field :name %></div>

<% end %>

<div class="buttons"><%= f.submit t('.signup'), class:"btn btn-primary" %><br>
<%= render "links" %></div>
<% end %>
```

updated

Company controller :

```
class CompaniesController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
  @company = Company.new
  @user = @company.users.build
end

def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])
  @user = User.create(params[:user].merge(company_id:company.id))
  if @company.save
   redirect_to "/"
  else
   render 'users/sign_up'
 end
 end
end
```

User Controller :

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user]) 
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render 'users/new'
    end
  end
```

I would really appreciate any idea and any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @Kyle i updated my question with code of two controllers

Answer (score 4):

In your case, since you are only interested in receiving the *company_name* I'd simplify it and submit the *company_name* via a `text_field_tag`.

In other words, I would replace:

```
<%= f.fields_for :company_attributes do |f_company| %>

<div class="control-group"><%= f_company.label :name, t('.company_name') %>
<%= f_company.text_field :name %></div>

<% end %>
```

With this

```rb
<%= text_field_tag 'company_name', {placeholder:"Enter here the name of your company",class:"form-control"} %>
```

This would submit the name to the `UsersController`, and you could access it with `params[:company_name]` so the controller would look like this:

Users controller:

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user]) 
    #Create a company via 'user<->company' association using 'company_name'
    @company= @user.company.create(name: params[:company_name])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render 'users/new'
    end
  end
```